# i use tf.data.TFRecordDataset read tfcord , why the data i read is not right

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

when i use tf.data.TFRecordDataset read many tfrecords. I read the label and image from tfrecord. I use tensorboard summary the image,and i write the label into the log file.But when i look at the log file and tensorboard. The label and image is not Corresponding. As follows，My code to read tfrecrods.

```
def parser(record):
    features = tf.parse_single_example(record,
                                   features={
                                       'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
                                   })  # 取出包含image和label的feature对象
    recode_image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.uint8)
    real_image = tf.reshape(recode_image, shape=[38, 38, 1])
    lable = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int64)
    return real_image,lable

def read_data(file_path):
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    batch_size = 3
    data=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_path)
    dataset=data.map(parser).
                 shuffle(buffer_size=min_after_dequeue).
                 batch(batch_size=batch_size)
    dataset=dataset.repeat()
    dataset.prefetch(100)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    image_batch, lable_batch = iterator.get_next()
    image_batch=input_float(image_batch)
    return  image_batch,lable_batch
```

use read_data in main thread code is:

```
file_list=glob.glob("./tfcode/training_image/*.tfrecord")
file_list = list(
         map(lambda image: image.replace('\\', '/'), file_list))
image_batch, lable_batch= read_data(file_list)
tf.summary.image(tensor=image_batch,name="image")
input_lable = sess.run(lable_batch)
logger.info(input_lable)
```

As follows is what i look in tensorboard:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR3i2.png)

As follows is what i look in log file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPnFx.png)

the label of image which tensorboard summary is [1,3,3], but the log file is [3,3,3].

how can i deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg instead ot `tf.decode_raw` ?

```
def parser(record):
    features = tf.parse_single_example(record,
                                   features={
                                       'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
                                   })
    recode_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['image'], channels=1)
    real_image = tf.reshape(recode_image, shape=[38, 38])
    lable = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int64)
    return real_image,lable

def read_data(file_path):
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    batch_size = 3
    data=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_path)
    dataset=data.map(parser).
                 shuffle(buffer_size=min_after_dequeue).
                 batch(batch_size=batch_size)
    dataset=dataset.repeat()
    dataset.prefetch(100)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
    image_batch=input_float(image_batch) # I'm assuming you are rescalling the image to [0,1]
    return  image_batch,label_batch
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22062645)

Comment: Code added ! Sorry for my laziness =P

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.I will change the code.This is a good idea.